# Accidentally purchased two Apple care protection plans

Tags: iphone, warranty

I thought buying Apple Care would extend warranty by one year. 
But I wasn't knowing that there is an upper limit too! And so unknowingly I purchased 2 Apple care plans while purchasing my iPhone.

Now since a year has passed. Is there anything I can do with the red coloured box I have? Can I use it with an iPhone 6S or maybe 7 that I'll buy next year?

Also there aren't Apple stores in India.

Comment: I think there are few apple stores in india, check this http://www.apple.com/in/contact/

Comment: Actually there aren't.. Those are Apple shops, where Apple trained employees work. No Genius here. Any information regarding whether I'll be able to use it with my future iPhone?

Comment: I don't know about that, you need to contact apple by email or phone and ask them or read the contract you got by email, there must something in it telling if you can or can't transfer the extended warranty to another phone. Personally, I don't think that's possible.